# Spring PetClinic and HttpRequest session

Tags: java, spring, session, spring-mvc

I am playing with the SpringPetClinic application and I am thinking of ways to capture the HttpRequest session for a particular request. I want to capture the unique session-id for the request to trace all the method calls this request makes and tie it together using the session-id. The idea would be to grab the HttpRequest session in the controller, store it in a Threadlocal variable and use the value of this variable and append it with log strings before a method is invoked and after the same method is done with its invocation.

My question is, what is the best way to get the HttpRequest session within the controller class of a SpringMVC project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an [`@InitBinder` method](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-webdatabinder) with a parameter of type `HttpSession`

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(HttpSession session) {
    myThreadLocal.set(session.getSessionId());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do

```
private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
```